# Cached pages is affecting jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQM for my hybrid app. Each page is a separate HTML file and JQM is loading the pages using Ajax.

Each pages has a footer with a menu bar. Depending on some criteria's, 2-4 menu items is shown. If I have to remove some menu items, I run a js script and it starts with:

```
var footer = $('#' + activePage +' footer [data-role="navbar"]');
```

The active page is set using this code:

```
var activePage; // Global variable

$(document).on( "pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( e, ui ) {
   activePage = ui.toPage.prop("id");
});
```

The problem is that after I navigate through a couple of pages, I suddenly have 2 footers. So when I count the number of `<li>` items, I get for example 2 + 4. 2 from the first footer and 4 from the second.

What can I do to avoid retrieving the cached pages?

Comment: Is one of the footers hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pagecontainer widget has a method, **[getActivePage()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-getActivePage)**, which does what you want.

So you could do something like this:

```
var footer = $("body").pagecontainer( "getActivePage" ).find('.ui-footer [data-role="navbar"]');
```

Then you don't need to try and save the active page id on page show anymore.

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/oj5ppryj/)**